# Why doesn't this Plnkr work when I download it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I'm new to Angular.js and have been playing around with it on Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/jR9VfaEhjUfY0vN7mfWd

The Plnkr Preview shows the Tabs and Partials loading fine but when I download it my computer only the Tabs work, why aren't the Partials displaying? Hope this screenshot explains my predicament:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: You need to run it on a web server (localhost) otherwise you will get this error: `Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Press F12 in chrome to get the debug console.

Comment: Never thought of checking the console, im new to Javascript in general. Just checked the console and got the error jpmorin mentioned. Running it on a web server works. Thanks!

Comment: @jpmorin do you want to put that as an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the page using a web server so there is no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" violation. When a script from `example1.com` tries to make AJAX request on `example2.com`, browsers first check if `example2.com` allows access from other website. This is done by reading `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of `example2.com`. Most websites normally don't allow AJAX access.

In your case, the origin is `file:///...` which won't be setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and since the default is to block the request, you get the error.

To get past this, do the following (Make sure you have ruby or python installed) -

1. Open command prompt
2. Use `cd` command to switch to your project directory ([tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Directories-in-Command-Prompt))
3. Type either of the command

   ```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer for python
   ```

   or

   ```
   ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 8000 . for ruby.
   ```

This will run a basic HTTP server at port 8000. The HTTP server will allow access to files in the directory you have run the command from. So if you have, for e.g, `index.html` in the directory, you could do `http://localhost:8000/index.html`

---

Looking at the screenshot, you can do this -

1. Open command prompt
2. run

   ```
   cd C:/Users/Jonny/Desktop/plunker
   ```
3. start server

   ```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer
   ```
4. Open `http://localhost:8000/index.html#/invoices` in your browser.

Comment: I don't have Python installed, im using xampp, but you have answered the question in the first paragraph so you can leave it at that :)

Comment: Great. Good old `xampp` should do fine. :D